# Extract values from list of tuples continuously in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang from a Ruby background and having some difficulty grasping the thought process. The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

I need to make the same request to an api, each time I receive a unique ID in the response which I need to pass into the next request until there is not ID returned. From each response I need to extract certain data and use it for other things as well.

First get the iterator:

```
ShardIteratorResponse = kinetic:get_shard_iterator(GetShardIteratorPayload).
{ok,[{<<"ShardIterator">>,
      <<"AAAAAAAAAAGU+v0fDvpmu/02z5Q5OJZhPo/tU7fjftFF/H9M7J9niRJB8MIZiB9E1ntZGL90dIj3TW6MUWMUX67NEj4GO89D"...>>}]}
```

Parse out the shard_iterator..

```
{_, [{_, ShardIterator}]} = ShardIteratorResponse.
```

Make the request to kinesis for the streams records...

```
GetRecordsPayload = [{<<"ShardIterator">>, <<ShardIterator/binary>>}].
[{<<"ShardIterator">>,
  <<"AAAAAAAAAAGU+v0fDvpmu/02z5Q5OJZhPo/tU7fjftFF/H9M7J9niRJB8MIZiB9E1ntZGL90dIj3TW6MUWMUX67NEj4GO89DETABlwVV"...>>}]
14> RecordsResponse = kinetic:get_records(GetRecordsPayload).
{ok,[{<<"NextShardIterator">>,
      <<"AAAAAAAAAAFy3dnTJYkWr3gq0CGo3hkj1t47ccUS10f5nADQXWkBZaJvVgTMcY+nZ9p4AZCdUYVmr3dmygWjcMdugHLQEg6x"...>>},
     {<<"Records">>,
      [{[{<<"Data">>,<<"Zmlyc3QgcmVjb3JkISEh">>},
         {<<"PartitionKey">>,<<"BlanePartitionKey">>},
         {<<"SequenceNumber">>,
          <<"49545722516689138064543799042897648239478878787235479554">>}]}]}]}
```

What I am struggling with is how do I write a loop that keeps hitting the kinesis endpoint for that stream until there are no more shard iterators, aka I want all records. Since I can't re-assign the variables as I would in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING: My code might be bugged but it's "close". I've never ran it and don't see how last iterator can look like.

I see you are trying to do your job entirely in shell. It's possible but hard. You can use named function and recursion [(since release 17.0 it's easier)](http://joearms.github.io/2014/02/01/big-changes-to-erlang.html), for example:

```
F = fun (ShardIteratorPayload) ->
    {_, [{_, ShardIterator}]} = kinetic:get_shard_iterator(ShardIteratorPayload),
    FunLoop =
        fun Loop(<<>>, Accumulator) ->  % no clue how last iterator can look like
                lists:reverse(Accumulator);
            Loop(ShardIterator, Accumulator) ->
                {ok, [{_, NextShardIterator}, {<<"Records">>, Records}]} =
                    kinetic:get_records([{<<"ShardIterator">>, <<ShardIterator/binary>>}]),
                Loop(NextShardIterator, [Records | Accumulator])
        end,
    FunLoop(ShardIterator, [])
end.
AllRecords = F(GetShardIteratorPayload).
```

But it's too complicated to type in shell...

It's much easier to code it in modules. 
A common pattern in erlang is to spawn another process or processes to fetch your data. To keep it simple you can spawn another process by calling [`spawn or spawn_link`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-1) but don't bother with links now and use just `spawn/3`.
Let's compile simple consumer module:

```
-module(kinetic_simple_consumer).

-export([start/1]).

start(GetShardIteratorPayload) ->
    Pid = spawn(kinetic_simple_fetcher, start, [self(), GetShardIteratorPayload]),
    consumer_loop(Pid).

consumer_loop(FetcherPid) ->
    receive
        {FetcherPid, finished} ->
            ok;
        {FetcherPid, {records, Records}} ->
            consume(Records),
            consumer_loop(FetcherPid);
        UnexpectedMsg -> 
            io:format("DROPPING:~n~p~n", [UnexpectedMsg]),
            consumer_loop(FetcherPid)
    end.

consume(Records) ->
    io:format("RECEIVED:~n~p~n",[Records]).
```

And fetcher:

```
-module(kinetic_simple_fetcher).

-export([start/2]).

start(ConsumerPid, GetShardIteratorPayload) ->
    {ok, [ShardIterator]} = kinetic:get_shard_iterator(GetShardIteratorPayload),
    fetcher_loop(ConsumerPid, ShardIterator).

fetcher_loop(ConsumerPid, {_, <<>>}) -> % no clue how last iterator can look like
    ConsumerPid ! {self(), finished};

fetcher_loop(ConsumerPid, ShardIterator) ->
    {ok, [NextShardIterator, {<<"Records">>, Records}]} = 
        kinetic:get_records(shard_iterator(ShardIterator)),
    ConsumerPid ! {self(), {records, Records}},
    fetcher_loop(ConsumerPid, NextShardIterator).

shard_iterator({_, ShardIterator}) ->
    [{<<"ShardIterator">>, <<ShardIterator/binary>>}].
```

As you can see both processes can do their job concurrently.
Try from your shell:

```
kinetic_simple_consumer:start(GetShardIteratorPayload).
```

Now your see that your shell process turns to consumer and you will have your shell back after fetcher will send `{ItsPid, finished}`.

Next time instead of

```
kinetic_simple_consumer:start(GetShardIteratorPayload).
```

run:

```
spawn(kinetic_simple_consumer, start, [GetShardIteratorPayload]).
```

You should play with spawning processes - it's erlang main strength.

Answer (score 0):

In Erlang, you can write loop using tail recursive functions. I don't know the kinetic API, so for simplicity, I just assume, that `kinetic:next_iterator/1` return `{ok, NextIterator}` or `{error, Reason}` when there are no more shards.

```
loop({error, Reason}) ->
    ok;
loop({ok, Iterator}) ->
    do_something_with(Iterator),
    Result = kinetic:next_iterator(Iterator),
    loop(Result).
```

You are replacing loop with iteration. First clause deals with case, where there are no more shards left (always start recursion with the end condition). Second clause deals with case, where we got some iterator, we do something with it and call next.

The recursive call is last instruction in the function body, which is called *tail recursion*. Erlang optimizes such calls - they don't use call stack, so they can run infinitely in constant memory (you will not get anything like "Stack level too deep")